# iOS app API calls blocked by App Transport Security

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I'm upgrading my server API calls to pass the ATS (App Transport Security) requirements from Apple. My server now has an A+ score after checking at [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mobile.singpost.com).

Why does ATS still block the connection?

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

How can we pass the ATS requirements? Do I need to make additional change to our server API call?

Comment: I don't know why you are still blocked (maybe you have to wait a little bit if you change your server now) you can still use below ats the allow arbitrary load to true and bypass security

Comment: I thought from Jan 1 2017. App will be rejected if still has allow arbitrary load set to true? Any other way to check if api call can pass the ATS?

Comment: I don't really know :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your app is still trying to access the server in http and not https. Have you reviewed all the urls that your app is accessing?

Maybe your server send the application redirects to an http site?

Try to add a breakpoint on your networking layer and review the urls you are trying access.

Comment: Thanks. Just figure out my api url still use http. Fix by change to https